# Why is my Audio not playing when I hover the Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

My Repeating Radial Gradient is not playing the Audio.
Can somebody help? I think I have an issue with ids.
The first link is code the second is the site.
https://github.com/Robocop79/Websiteland/blob/master/index.html
https://robocop79.github.io/Websiteland/

Answer (score 0):

The main problems in your Javascript code are:

- There's no element with id `nav-two` in the HTML, did you mean `grad1`?
- You are cloning audio `<source>` elements, but `.play()` can only be executed on `<audio>`

```
$("#grad1 a").each(function(i) {
  if (i != 0) {
    $("#bay").parent()
    .clone()
    .attr("id", "bay" + i)
    .appendTo($(this).parent());
  }
  $(this).data("bay", i);
})
.mouseenter(function() {
  $("#bay" + $(this).data("bay"))[0].play();
});
```

You can also simplify the way the audio triggers by moving mouseenter call inside the `.each` function (and therefore removing the need for `data` attributes).

```
$("#grad1 a").each(function(i) {
  if (i != 0) {
    var clonedaudio = $("#bay").parent()
      .clone()
      .appendTo($(this).parent());

    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
      clonedaudio[0].play();
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: trigger is the id

Comment: @Robocop79 I edited my post, that code keeps the ids

Comment: @Robocop79 I don't have any good suggestions right now, sorry. Your initial Javascript code had the right ideas, you simply had two small things wrong :) I guess you should keep trying, Google errors, read Jquery and Javascript documentation, learn the basics, you'll eventually get there.

Comment: https://robocop79.github.io/Websiteland/blackandyellow7seconds.mp3
    This is the mp3 file for hovering over the div

Comment: https://robocop79.github.io/Websiteland/baydiv https://github.com/Robocop79/Websiteland/blob/master/baydiv.html The first link is the seperate version for testing and the second is the code seperate